# How do I fix this error in IMPORTXML in Google Sheets?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I am trying to import current price of a fund from sg.finance.com.yahoo into Google sheets. The ticker is an ISIN code. I have checked and identified the url (it is, in this case, https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/0P0000ZSIN.SI). I have copied the full XPath for price, in this case /html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/fin-streamer[1]) and checked it using XPath Helper in Chrome, and it correctly highlights the price.

So my formula is:

=IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/0P0000ZSIN.SI" , "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/fin-streamer[1]")

I have checked it a few times and can't see where I am going wrong.

Does any kind soul see an error?

Cheers, any input appreciated.
Worminger

As above, I have double checked the url, and I have used XPath Helper to check the relevant element.

Comment: While that URL loads correctly in my browser, If I try fetching it with `curl`, I get back a 404 error page. I suspect that `IMPORTXML` is running into a similar problem. It looks like that page may only render correctly in an actual browser.

Comment: Thanks. It seems therefore not to work with the Singapore version of Yahoo Finance, whereas I believe this method does work with Yahoo Finance generally. Very odd. I wonder if anyone else has any knowledge or insight into whether Yahoo implements differently between their sites for this purpose, or whether they have started blocking web scraping?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IMPORTXML can't parse complicated code structures correctly. As a workaround we can use Google Script and in particular [UrlFetchApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). The fetched data has the required "fin-streamer"-tag value. So we can extract it using a regular expression.

```
function getFinStreamerData() {
  const URL = 'https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/0P0000ZSIN.SI?guccounter=1';
  /*
  
  The response contains the substring like this:    
  <fin-streamer class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-symbol="0P0000ZSIN.SI" data-test="qsp-price" data-field="regularMarketPrice" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" value="20.34" active="">20.34</fin-streamer>

  */
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  Logger.log(resp.getResponseCode());
  var m = resp.getContentText().match(/>([\d.]+)<\/fin-streamer>/);
  if (m) Logger.log(m[1]);  // Required value, like 20.34
}
```